# How to item balance

Tags: mysql

What's the Error in This query

```
SELECT 
  i.`Item Desc` AS ItemDesc,
  t.Trans_date AS Trans_date,
  t.B1 AS B1
FROM (item As i
  JOIN trans As t
    ON ((i.Item_code = t.Item_code)))
WHERE t.Trans_date = (SELECT MAX(t1.Trans_date) As trans_date
                                    FROM trans AS t1
                                    WHERE (trans.Trans_date <= '2019-08-31')
                                    AND t1.Item_code = i.Item_code)
```

Comment: What error you are receiving ?

Comment: Not description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue(s) with your query:

- If you are giving an alias to a table use that alias for each reference. issue: `FROM trans AS t1 WHERE (trans.Trans_date <= '2019-08-31')`, here `trans` table is aliased as `t1` and you are using again full name with `trans.Trans_date`.

```
SELECT 
    i.`Item Desc` AS ItemDesc,
    t.Trans_date AS Trans_date,
    t.B1 AS B1
FROM item AS i
INNER JOIN trans AS t ON i.Item_code = t.Item_code
WHERE t.Trans_date = (SELECT MAX(t1.Trans_date) As trans_date
                     FROM trans t1
                     WHERE t1.Trans_date <= '2019-08-31'
                     AND t1.Item_code = i.Item_code);
```